# Calling and printing counter function elements

Tags: python, for-loop

I am a rookie programmer who just started and was trying to do a hacker rank challenge but I am stumped. Below is the code I am working with and I cant seem to figure out what i am doing wrong. I want to print str_con, but its not working

```
from collections import Counter

X = 10 # no of shoes available in a store

str = (2,3,4,5,6,8,7,6,5,18 ) # shoe sizes available 

str_con = Counter(str) #how many pairs of each size are available

for i in str_con:
    if i in x:
        profit += size_price.get(i)
        size_price.items-1
```

how do I print str_con ?

Comment: What have you tried? `print(str_con)`? What happens? How is it different from what you want?

Comment: Where did `size_price` come from? Its not defined in your code. `i in X` doesn't make any sense, because an `int` is not a container.

Comment: I would not try to solve any "challenges" until you've worked through some of the [tutuorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) to get a feel for the language.

Comment: This code looks like complete guesswork; there are several problems with it that have nothing to do with printing `str_con`, which makes it hard to even begin to answer your question about the counter.  Start with something simpler.

Comment: You are advised not to use `str` as a variable name, because it is the name of the built-in string type.

Answer (score 0):

Let's begin with some pointers regharding future programing style Do's and Don'ts most of which have been mentioned by previous commentors.

1. Using `str` as a variable name, while valid lexatically, is frowned upon since str is the name of a native python object type.  In your specific program it doesn't seem to cause a problem, but wlii result in strange program behavior as you start to construct more complex problems.
2. str is a variable which is shown as a tuple. Thisn is again not good programming practice.
3. Using variable names which don't reflect their purpose of rationale is also not good practice.  For short problems like your example, we all do it from time to time, but as you begin to build more complex programs you should strive to provide meaningful names to variables.  This would also hold for the variable profit, since it seems to be the result of extracting the shoe price from a undefined class size_price having a function get.
4. When building a new function make use of the type hinting capability  to ensure future readers of your code have an idea of its purpose, function and parameters.

Now that I have given a few pointer on programming style, here are my comments on your code:
**Problem Statement:** - print the number of pairs of shoes by size.

**Given:**
shoe_count as integer
shoe_sizes as tuple of integers

**Methodology**

1. Use Collection Counter to count the occurrences of shoe sizes
   **Note:** Counter returns a dictionary type data structure

Here is how I would code your problem:

```
from collections import Counter

def countShoeSizes(shoe_count: int, shoe_sizes: tuple[int]) -> None:
    shoe_inventory = Counter(shoe_sizes)  #Note Counter returns a dict type structure
    for sze, nmb in shoe_inventory.items():
        print(f'Shoe Size {sze},\t Qty: {nmb} pairs')
```

The shoe_count variable is not needed, since it has no bearing on the code as written, but could be useful if you desired to add error checking.